# Rounded Curve Tabs | Css

Tags: css, html

Hi, I am trying to have the rounded corner tabs in CSS which should be supported in all browsers..

Here is the link which i had tried ..

http://learneveryday.net/demo/css/menu/tabmenu1/

Everything works ok..but rounded corners are not coming..

Here is the HTML code for that..

```
<ul id="navtabs">
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-8"><a href="#">Blogging</a></li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-6 current-cat"><a href="#">Branding</a></li>

    <li class="cat-item cat-item-10"><a href="#">Freelancing</a></li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-3"><a href="#">Marketing</a></li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-5"><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
</ul>
```

When I open the CSS, they have included images. I am unable to find that..

Let me know where can I get the images

Comment: -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
-moz-border-radius: 8px;
border-radius: 8px;

Comment: Its working fine. What browser you are looking at?

Comment: Use `border-radius`, and read up on `Progressive enhancement` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use css only, if your browser supports it:

```
-webkit-border-radius: 1px;
-moz-border-radius: 1px;
border-radius: 1px;
```

Radius generator: http://border-radius.com/

Compatibility list: http://caniuse.com/border-radius

Alternatively you could use a sprite image: http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `-webkit` for chrome and `-moz` for Mozilla

```
.RoundBorder
{
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use border-radius to get rounded corners.

Specifically `border-top-left-radius` and `border-top-right-radius`

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uR58P/) for an example

Comment: better use `border-radius: 9px 9px 0 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
    <ul class="round" id="navtabs">
<li class="cat-item cat-item-8"><a href="#">Blogging</a></li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-6 current-cat"><a href="#">Branding</a></li>

<li class="cat-item cat-item-10"><a href="#">Freelancing</a></li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-3"><a href="#">Marketing</a></li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-5"><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
```

```
    .round { -webkit-border-radius:6px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it with `border-radius:7px 7px 0 0;`. For any new browser, you don't need `-webkit-`